# React native - firebase authentication with react-redux in App.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using Firebase authentication and react-redux in my app. I added `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to my App.js's `componentDidMount` function to check for user login status throughout the app. I tried connecting App.js to my redux actions's function `getUserProfile` like this:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'; 
import reducers from './app/src/reducers';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { firebase } from './config/config';
import { getUserProfile } from './app/src/actions/index';

...

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    var that = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
        if (user) {
            await that.getUserProfile(user.uid);
        } else {
            that.navigation.navigate('Auth');
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      user: state.auth.user
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getUserProfile})(App);
```

I got the error: **Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.** How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem now. You are using *connect* on a component that is the parent of the *Provider* component.

What you need to do is create a new component called *Main* and use *connect* on that. Your *App* component cannot use connect because it is not a child of *Provider*, instead it is the parent.

Or in other words:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'; 
import reducers from './app/src/reducers';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

...

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { firebase } from './config/config';
import { getUserProfile } from './app/src/actions/index';

...

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    var that = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
        if (user) {
            await that.getUserProfile(user.uid);
        } else {
            that.navigation.navigate('Auth');
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      user: state.auth.user
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getUserProfile})(Main);
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, other components do not need to call Main itself right? Because it is contained by App.js

Comment: Only issue is now I am getting `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'that.navigation.navigate')` inside componentDidMount in main.js

Comment: Strange. Maybe try passing navigation={this.navigation} down to Main.

Comment: I don't follow, MainStack is just a switch navigator with different stacks inside of it

Comment: Usually, passing `navigation={this.navigation}` down to the component would fix it but in this case, main.js imports react-navigation directly...

Comment: This is how I usually navigate: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: The reason this issue started is because I want to call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` only once instead of in every screen. Maybe App.js or Main.js isn't the right place for that